# Youtube embed in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, youtube, embed

I am trying to embed an interval of a youtube video on my wordpress.
I have managed to set the start and final point that i want.
The problem is when the video ends, I want to make an option to restart the video but from the starting point I´ve set, not from the begining of the video.
Any idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the youtube embed start parameter is what you're looking for. Check out the [youtube developers page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Or use [iframe api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onStateChange) and catch ending of video and programmicaly start play video again.